# why does this code keep coming up with errors. xCode 4.6

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
NSImageCell *imageFromBundle;     
NSData *imageData;     
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.greatwhatsit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/jeremiah1.jpg"];     
NSLog(@"url");     
NSLog(@"data");     
NSImage *imageFromBundle = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

why doesn't this code work. xcode 4.6

Comment: it comes up with "Redefinition of 'imageFromBundle' with a different type: 'NSImage *_strong' vs 'NSImageCell *_strong' what the heck, I have changed everything and it is still coming up with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Also you need to init imageData:

```
imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
NSImage *imageFromBundle = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the same type for the definition and init of `imageFromBundle`

```
NSImageCell *imageFromBundle;
NSImage *imageFromBundle = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

Change to:

```
NSImage *imageFromBundle;
NSImage *imageFromBundle = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

Also, as zakhej sais, you need to init `imageData`

Comment: comes up with redefinition of imageFromBundle? I just started programming yesterday, sorry.

Comment: First try to replace `NSImageCell` with `NSImage`. That should solve the error you described.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.greatwhatsit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/jeremiah1.jpg"];    
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];  
NSLog(@"url");     
NSLog(@"data");     
NSImage *imageFromBundle = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: thanks so much. All I need to do now is create correct me if I am wrong a NSObject *imageFromBundle in order for it to load the variable. It says it is unused variable *imageFromBundle.

Comment: As per your code, u declared imageFromBundle in two places for NSImage & NSImageCell. For that reason may be u used one out of it.

Answer (score 0):

imageFromBundle  was the first issue as has been pointed out.
But other issues existed like not the imageData only being declared but not being given any data.

Also You can *initWithContentsOfURL* directly in a NSImage.

```
  NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjno3.jpg?s=32&g=1"];
    NSImage * aImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    [_imageWellOutlet setImage: aImage]; //-- declared in .h header file
                                            //--  ( @property  (weak) IBOutlet NSImageView *imageWellOutlet;)
```